# ECS with CDK, Service deployment fails, instance doesn't have access to internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am trying to self-host plausible analytics, and for that I need a `clickhouse` instance. I decided to have the following setup

An ASG that will provide the instances to my cluster, by registering it as a capacity provider. Then I create my service, task definition and everything to run the clickhouse image.

EDIT: After running the [automation to troubleshoot the issue I get the following output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager-automation-runbooks/latest/userguide/automation-aws-troubleshoot-ecs-container-instance.html)

```
The container instance profile PlausibleStack-ClickHouseAutoScalingGroupInxxxxxx3c1Rx5YEV is missing the following required permission(s): 
['ecs:RegisterContainerInstance', 'ecs:CreateCluster', 'ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance', 'ecs:Poll', 'ecs:StartTelemetrySession', 'ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState', 'ecs:SubmitAttachmentStateChange', 'ecs:SubmitContainerStateChange', 'ecs:SubmitTaskStateChange']
Make sure that the container instance has all the recommended permissions.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/security-iam-awsmanpol.html#instance-iam-role-permissions

It seems like the container instance doesn't have communication with ECS service endpoint. Container instances need access to communicate with the Amazon ECS service endpoint. This can be through an interface VPC endpoint or through your container instances having public IP addresses. For more information about interface VPC endpoints, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints.html
If you do not have an interface VPC endpoint configured and your container instances do not have public IP addresses, then they must use network address translation (NAT) to provide this access. For more information, see NAT gateways in the Amazon VPC User Guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) and HTTP proxy configuration in this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/http_proxy_config.html. For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-public-private-vpc.html
```

```
service PlausibleStack-ClickHouseService22DFxxxxxfGo was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container Instances were found in your cluster. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide.
```

User data of the instance is correct

```bash
#!/bin/bash
docker plugin install rexray/ebs REXRAY_PREEMPT=true EBS_REGION=eu-central-1 --grant-all-permissions
systemctl restart ecs
echo ECS_CLUSTER=PlausibleStack-ClusterEB038xxxxxARS3re >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
sudo iptables --insert FORWARD 1 --in-interface docker+ --destination 169.254.169.254/32 --jump DROP
sudo service iptables save
echo ECS_AWSVPC_BLOCK_IMDS=true >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

This is the CDK code I am using to set this up

```js
// somewhere else
        this.vpc.addInterfaceEndpoint('CloudWatchLogsEndpoint', {
            service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.CLOUDWATCH_LOGS,
        });
        this.vpc.addInterfaceEndpoint('CloudWatchEndpoint', {
            service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.CLOUDWATCH,
        });
        this.vpc.addInterfaceEndpoint('EcsEndpoint', {
            service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECS,
        });
        this.vpc.addInterfaceEndpoint('EcsAgentEndpoint', {
            service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECS_AGENT,
        });
        this.vpc.addInterfaceEndpoint('EcsTelemetryEndpoint', {
            service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECS_TELEMETRY,
        });

    private setupInstances() {
        const userData = ec2.UserData.forLinux();
        // https://medium.com/aspecto/attach-ebs-docker-volume-to-aws-ecs-using-cdk-931c29e0e1
        userData.addCommands(
            `docker plugin install rexray/ebs REXRAY_PREEMPT=true EBS_REGION=${ConstValues.region} --grant-all-permissions`,
            "systemctl restart ecs"
        );

        const autoScalingGroup = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(this, 'ClickHouseAutoScalingGroup', {
            vpc: this.vpc,
            vpcSubnets: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS },
            minCapacity: 1,
            maxCapacity: 1,
            instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t2.micro'),
            machineImage: ecs.EcsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux2(),
            userData
        });

        autoScalingGroup.role.attachInlinePolicy(ec2PolicyEbs);
        const ecsPermissions = new Policy(this, 'ECSPermissions', {
            policyName: 'ECSPermissions',
            statements: [
                new PolicyStatement({
                    effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                    actions: [
                        'ecs:RegisterContainerInstance',
                        'ecs:CreateCluster',
                        'ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance',
                        'ecs:Poll',
                        'ecs:StartTelemetrySession',
                        'ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState',
                        'ecs:SubmitAttachmentStateChange',
                        'ecs:SubmitContainerStateChange',
                        'ecs:SubmitTaskStateChange',
                    ],
                    resources: ['*'],
                }),
            ],
        });

        autoScalingGroup.role.attachInlinePolicy(ecsPermissions);

        const capacityProvider = new ecs.AsgCapacityProvider(this, 'ClickHouseAsgCapacityProvider', {
            autoScalingGroup,
            machineImageType: ecs.MachineImageType.AMAZON_LINUX_2,
        });

        this.cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider);
    }

    private setupClickHouse() {
        this.clickhouseSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'ClickHouseSecurityGroup', {
            vpc: this.vpc,
            allowAllOutbound: true
        });

        this.clickhouseSecret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'ClickhouseSecret');

        const VOLUME_NAME = 'clickhouse-data';

        const taskDef = new ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(this, 'ClickHouseTask', {
            volumes: [{
                name: VOLUME_NAME,
                dockerVolumeConfiguration: {
                    autoprovision: true,
                    scope: ecs.Scope.SHARED,
                    driver: 'rexray/ebs',
                    driverOpts: {
                        volumetype: 'gp2',
                        size: '10',
                    },
                }
            }],
            networkMode: ecs.NetworkMode.AWS_VPC,
        });

        const container = taskDef.addContainer('Clickhouse', {
            image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('clickhouse/clickhouse-server:23.3.7.5-alpine'),
            memoryLimitMiB: 512,
        });

        // Attach the EBS volume to the task
        container.addMountPoints({
            containerPath: '/var/lib/clickhouse',
            sourceVolume: VOLUME_NAME,
            readOnly: false
        });

        container.addPortMappings({
            containerPort: 8123,
        });

        new ecs.Ec2Service(this, 'ClickHouseService', {
            cluster: this.cluster,
            taskDefinition: taskDef,
            securityGroups: [this.clickhouseSecurityGroup],
            desiredCount: 1,
        });
    }
```

I tried having NAT gateways as well, but it always results in same error, considering the endpoints, and the permissions are in place, I am a bit confused as to why the connection issue

EDIT2: Latest run of automation to troubleshoot the issue results in

```
Unable to identify the cause of issue.
If you are still experiencing issues while registering EC2Instance('i-0b7bxxxxxf4') in the cluster named PlausibleStack-ClusterEB0386A7-2qQI7w5VzgIj, please open a case with Premium Support and attach the logs generated by the ECS Logs Collector script.
See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-logs-collector.html
If it is not possible to upload the file while case creation, please ask the assigned engineer to provide the instruction to upload the file.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be caused by the option `memoryLimitMiB: 1024`. Although you have an `T3.micro` instance with 1GB (1024MiB) of memory, not all memory are available to the container. The platform overhead and system kernel occupies some memory of that 1GB.

Try to lower the memory (if possible) or use a bigger instance.

Comment: That was one of my ideas as well! How could I debug this in the future? Shouldn't it say somewhere, "trying instance X, memory not appropriate"? But unfortunately, this is not the issue, tried both `512` and using `t2.small` and still the same result. Ideally, I'd debug this, and not try and guess, hopefully there is a way to get insight on what's happening

Comment: Yeah, the debug information is not great, it's missing specific information to pinpoint the actual problem. If the container instance is not being added to the cluster (you have verified under tab Infrastructure in the Cluster), it could be a permission error. Try to use the `AWSSupport-TroubleshootECSContainerInstance` runbook to see if you get some information. [Read more here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager-automation-runbooks/latest/userguide/automation-aws-troubleshoot-ecs-container-instance.html).

Comment: It looks like you have placed the container instance in an isolated subnet. It needs Internet access to communicate with the ECS service endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the automation link, that was super useful. After a whole day of debugging, I got a better understanding of the services I am using. To an extent, I understand the issue and what's happening. But I am still unable to make it work. I'll update the question with my newfound ideas